# create javascript data structure from meteor pub/sub events?

Tags: templates, meteor

i have a very simple meteor app that currently just displays updates from the backend mongo store.

```
<head>
  <title>dc-meteor</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div name="heatmap">
    <canvas id="heatmap" width="1000px" height="1000px"></canvas>
  </div>
  <script>

  var data = [
    [ 350,280, 32 ],
    [ 120,120, 28 ],
    [ 230,330, 35 ],
    [ 440,240, 12 ],
    [ 640,540, 60 ],
    [ 650,670, 70 ],
    [ 680,500, 30 ],
    [ 690,340, 43 ],
    [ 500,440, 38 ],
    [ 550,240, 43 ],
    [ 350,640, 49 ],
    [ 580,540, 47 ]
  ];
  var plan = new Image();
  plan.src = "images/floor2.svg";
  plan.onload = function(){
    var canvas = $('#heatmap');
    var ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage( plan,0,0, 1000, 1000 * plan.height / plan.width );
  };
  var heat = simpleheat('heatmap').data(data).max(20).radius( 10,40 );

  heat.draw(0.8);
  </script>

  {{> sensor_list}}

</body>

<template name="sensor_list">
  <div class="sensor_list">
    {{#each sensors}}
        {{> sensor_item}}
    {{/each}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="sensor_item">
  <div class="sensor_item">
    <p>{{_id}}: time={{ts}} {{temp}}C {{humidity}}%</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

as you can see, i have meteor live updating the data into `sensor_list` template, however, i would also like to build the `data` variable to contain the live data.

how do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [`Tracker.autorun`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun) to update the heatmap. Inside a javascript file (not in a `<script>` tag):

```js
Template.body.rendered = function () {
    var heatmap = simpleheat("heatmap");
    this.autorun(function () {
        var data = calculateTheDataSomehow();
        heatmap.data(data).draw(0.8);
    });
}
```

If your `calculateTheDataSomehow()` accesses a reactive data source (like a collection) then the `autorun` function will re-run whenever the data changes, updating the heatmap.

The code is put in `Template.body.rendered` so it is only run when the body template has initially rendered.

Here I've used `this.autorun` which is a special version of `Tracker.autorun` which automatically stops auto-updating when the template is removed. In this case the template is `Template.body` which is never removed, but it's a good habit anyway.

Comment: thanks for the indepth description; i also found that `observe` works for me; what are the pros and cons of using `autorun` over observe on a collection?

Comment: `observe` only gives you the changes, whereas `autorun` gives you the entire query each time it changes. So `observe` should be more efficient if you're able to efficiently merge the changes.